# Is there any UCI engine that presents DTZ information from syzygy in analyse mode?

Tags: tablebases, uci

Many UCI engines that can read syzygy database put same score for every winning move (#1000 in komodo, +123.53 in stockfish, ...) and you have no idea how to make real progress when analysing root positions with them. **Is there some UCI engine that scores move based on dtz value?**

I understand that this dtz value is something new and that it doesn't fit very well to standard way moves are scored by engines, but without this dtz value engine becomes useless when material is reduced to 6 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Stockfish has an undocumented, non-standard command "d" which prints, among other things, the DTZ value. Some interfaces, for example, Arena, let the user give commands to the engine manually.